# Network and Transport layer functionalities on Captured packets

Tags: linux, network-programming, tcp, libpcap, packet-capture

I have a Client and Server programs communicating on TCP, implementing IEC-60870-5-104 protocol on the application layer. I am sniffing a copy of all traffic between them, 
How do I exactly replicate the IP and TCP layer functionalities on packets sniffed from libpcap in C ?. like *IP-reassembly*, Managing *out-of-order* segments, *re-transmission*, and *duplicate* TCP segments and separating PDUs, such that I get the same packet as if I was sniffing on the application layer at the Server. (Also please suggest any Frame-works which helps to do this).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very difficult and involved task. It's what network intrusion detection / deep packet inspection systems do and AFAIK there is no drop-in library that handles it.

Your best bet is to build on an existing system such as Bro or Suricata (or maybe wireshark internals) that is already doing the session tracking, state management, re-assembly, re-ordering, duplicate detection, etc. You can then add your own application layer decoding to operate on the re-assembled data stream provided.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  In IEC-60870-5-104 protocol the frame size cannot be more than 256 bytes, it means the PDU size will be less than or equal to 256 octets. At server side program I am using one send() statement to send one IEC-104 frame. Likewise, if I use three consecutive send() statements without any delay between them, all the three frames will be packed into single TCP segment, hence the captured packet will have multiple frames. Is there any way I can separate them (Wireshark is able to identify each frame, how is it doing)

Comment: How will TCP indicate if the frame (PDU) is split and sent using two TCP segments

Comment: TCP won't indicate that. TCP provides a logical byte stream. It is up to the application layer to split it into messages/PDUs/frames or however the application wants to view the stream. So your application layer parser must be able to recognize the IEC "frames" and handle them accordingly.